# Why does RedirectToActionResult ControllerName return NULL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, xunit

I have a Xunit test class for a MVC:

```
using System;
using Xunit;
using Home.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Tester.Models;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{

    public class Class1
    {

        [Fact]
        public void CreateinController()
        {
            HomeController c = new HomeController();

            var result = c.Create();

            //result moet een view zijn
            var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);

            //Juiste redirection

            var result2 = c.Create(null);

            var redirectToActionResult =
            Assert.IsType<RedirectToActionResult>(result2);

            Assert.Equal("Home", redirectToActionResult.ControllerName);
            Assert.Equal("BoekingVerwerken", redirectToActionResult.ActionName);


        }


    }
}
```

Whenever I run the test the ActionName passes the test because it actually contains the value. But the ControllerName seems to be NULL valued, why is this?
When the Action has a value why wouldn't the Controller have one? Should I put the controller in the RTA?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Tester.Models;

namespace Home.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(HotelBoeking boeking)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("BoekingVerwerken", boeking);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult BoekingVerwerken(HotelBoeking boeking)
        {
            return View(boeking);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Controller.cs source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L515), you will see that `RedirectToAction` returns a `RedirectToRouteResult` type, not a `RedirectToActionResult` type.

As you can see from the [source code of RedirectToRouteResult.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/RedirectToRouteResult.cs), you can get the controller name from the `RouteValues` property. There is no `ControllerName` property on this type.

```
var redirectToRouteResult =
        Assert.IsType<RedirectToRouteResult>(result2);

Assert.Equal("Home", redirectToRouteResult.RouteValues["controller"]);
```

> I am not entirely sure the syntax for XUnit is correct, as I don't work with it much, but you should take away from this that because MVC is open source that questions like this one can be easily answered by inspecting the source code.